Archiving sitecore sites
I am working for a government client who have got their current websites developed in Sitecore. They are planning to move to other CMS and want to archive their Sitecore site. They have got requirement to archive their sites for future if got some request for archived items. Did some research that we can use web crawlers, some of them seemed not to work. Anyone who been through this, or any suggestion what/ how to get this done.
thanks

I have few suggestions for achieving this goal. Among them, I've only utilized the "Export content" option to preserve the content for future references.
Static Site Generation: Consider converting the dynamic Sitecore website into a static site using tools like Jekyll, Hugo, or Gatsby. This process involves rendering the entire website into HTML files.
Export Content: Sitecore provides tools for exporting content. You can use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions or custom scripts to export content items to a format like JSON or XML, preserving their structure and metadata.
Web Crawlers: While web crawlers can be used to archive websites, they may not always capture dynamic content or complex interactions. However, tools like HTTrack or wget can still be useful for capturing a snapshot of the website's structure and static content.
Hope it helps!
